# MySQL query to find the count of matches in a column for every value in a given parameter list

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL 8.0.16, say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE example (letter VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO example VALUES ('v'),('w'),('x'),('y'),('z');
```

```
> SELECT * FROM example;
+--------+
| letter |
+--------+
| v      |
| w      |
| x      |
| y      |
| z      |
+--------+
```

I am trying to create a query that represents the question:

*"For each of the values in a given arbitrary list, tell me how many times those values occur in the `example.letter` column"*.

Within the given list, some subset of values may or may not occur in the `example.letter` column.

As an example, say we have the list `('a','b','x','y')`. Then I'm looking for the output:

```
> /* some query */
+--------+----------+
| letter |  count   |
+--------+----------+
| a      |        0 |
| b      |        0 |
| x      |        1 |
| y      |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

I can get the x,y part, but I can't seem to figure out how to get counts for items that don't exist!

```
SELECT letter, COUNT(*)
   FROM example
   WHERE letter in ('a','b','x','y')
   GROUP BY letter;
+--------+----------+
| letter | COUNT(*) |
+--------+----------+
| x      |        1 |
| y      |        1 |
+--------+----------+
/* I want the 0-counts for a and b to be here as well! */
```

Maybe this is surprisingly simple and possibly a duplicate due to me not searching for the right terms! Apologies if so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
SELECT v.letter, COUNT(e.letter)
FROM (SELECT 'a' as letter UNION ALL
      SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'x' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'y'
     ) v(letter) LEFT JOIN
     example e
     ON e.letter = v.letter
GROUP BY v.letter;
```

Comment: Thanks Gorden, it seems that MySQL (8.0.16) doesn't support VALUES used in that way however